# как пропарсить xmltable

Tags: plsql

```
    select  *
  from xmltable('pay_doc' passing xmltype(
                              '<pay_doc>
                                  <nom>18545885</nom>
                                  <filial_id>4</filial_id>
                                  <rko_id>1000</rko_id>
                                  <provider_id>2119</provider_id>
                                  <lic_id>607057</lic_id>
                                  <client_dat>20.07.2016</client_dat>
                                  <summ>24781</summ>
                                  <client_komis>150</client_komis>
                                  <input_summ>24931</input_summ>
                                  <client_fio>асан ләйлә ерғазықызы</client_fio>
                                  <client_address>мкр курылысшы ул кокорай д 18 кв 20</client_address>
                                  <client_phone>№ 808/14-01 от 29.10.2014</client_phone>
                                  <create_user_id>2600</create_user_id>
                                  <params>
                                     <param column = "SCHET_IZV">123456789</param>
                                     <param column = "PERIOD">234</param>
                                     <param column = "RES">0</param>
                                  </params>
                              </pay_doc>'
                          ) 
                columns 
                    nom             varchar2(255) path 'nom',
                    filial_id       varchar2(255) path 'filial_id',
                    rko_id          varchar2(255) path 'rko_id',
                    provider_id     varchar2(255) path 'provider_id',
                    lic_id          varchar2(255) path 'lic_id',
                    client_dat      varchar2(255) path 'client_dat',
                    summ            varchar2(255) path 'summ',
                    client_komis    varchar2(255) path 'client_komis',
                    input_summ      varchar2(255) path 'input_summ',
                    client_fio      varchar2(255) path 'client_fio',
                    client_address  varchar2(255) path 'client_address',
                    client_phone    varchar2(255) path 'client_phone',
                    create_user_id  varchar2(255) path 'create_user_id',

                    SCHET_IZV       varchar2(255) Path '@column',
                    PERIOD          varchar2(255) path 'params/text()',
                    RES             varchar2(255) path 'param/@RES'                    

                    ) с;
```

параметры `SCHET_IZV`, `PERIOD`, `RES` выходят пустыми.

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Если ответ вас полностью устроил, поставьте плиз "галочку" под рейтингом ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Пути поиска в вашем случае должны выглядеть так:

```
  SCHET_IZV       varchar2(255) Path 'params/param[@column="SCHET_IZV"]',
  PERIOD          varchar2(255) path 'params/param[@column="PERIOD"]',
  RES             varchar2(255) path 'params/param[@column="RES"]'
```